# Using QnA Conversation to trigger other tasks (ideally using Blue Prism)

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-qna-maker, blueprism

I have a feeling I'm missing something v obvious here, or perhaps I'm just using the wrong tools in the wrong order, or any combination of the above.

My company uses Blue Prism, and I'd like to build a virtual sales assistant that I can integrate into MS Teams. The idea being, the sales team can ask this bot to carry out a number of different tasks. The user thinks the bot is doing it, but in reality, the bot will be calling Blue Prism and triggering a separate process that has been built. We would integrate LUIS to attempt to split out all the different entities in the question and gradually narrow down what is what by replying to the original user question if it can't split them straight away.

I've built a brief knowledge base and integrated into Teams, however what I'm struggling with is learning how to actually have a central source read the messages asked by users within teams. I'd like to try and go directly to Blue Prism, but I'm aware that something like Flow or Automate may be an option, even if just to use this to trigger blue prism rather than it happening directly from Teams.

Any ideas? An example of a request may be - 'Log 100k pipeline app for the new product for mr smith.'

Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow's Q&A format ([How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). You should consider that Blue Prism isn't designed for instantaneous or real-time processing of requests. While it's possible to do so with BP, using something like Microsoft Bot Framework to interact on the Teams level would be more efficient & will make it easier to integrate with NLP (which you'll require, considering your example request). You would then have your Bot Framework-based solution interact with Blue Prism Processes exposed as Web Services to complete processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be getting a bit of crossed lines between LUIS and QnAMaker. QnAMaker, as the name implies, is specifically where you have Questions, and want to maintain a knowledge base of likely answers. In contrast, LUIS would be used here to more accurately identify the instruction being passed, and extracting the values from it. It certainly possible to *combine* the two into the same bot, i.e. having a bot that handles both *commands* **and** *questions*, but that doesn't sound like what you're trying to do.

As a result, you should be focusing more on LUIS, and defining the relevant entities and intents. As an example, "log pipeline" would be an "intent", whereas "100k", "new product", and "mr smith" would be entities that the bot would know to work with.

What the bot does behind the scenes with that intent+entities combination is of course totally up to what you choose as an implementation, Blue Prism or otherwise.